# adding significance to geom_violin plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I would like to significance plots between my two groups (X1 and X2) for example, in a way that there is a line above the two violins with the number of asterisks that corresponds (`*/**/***`). I'm trying to use  `geom_signif`.

This is my data

```
my_data=X1  50
            X1  30
            X1  40
            X1  30
            X1  40
            X1  33
            X1  45
            X1  54
            X1  34
            X1  54
            X2  77
            X2  80
            X2  70
            X2  60
            X2  55
            X2  77
            X2  79
            X2  80
            X2  82
            X2  83
            X3  10
            X3  12
            X3  14
            X3  15
            X3  12
            X3  12
            X3  11
            X3  9
            X3  8
            X3  10
```

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

my_colors = c('#33adff', '#0066ff', '#47d147')

ggplot(d, aes(x = variable, y =value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = TRUE) + 
  geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1, color = "black") +
  labs(y="A.U.") + 
  xlab('') +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(d$variable == "X1", d$variable == "X2")),
              map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

I'm getting an error:

> invalid argument to unary operator

What am I doing wrong? How can I change the last line so that it will take all the measurements of X1 and compare them to all of X2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(color=variable), trim = TRUE) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.1) +
  labs(y = "A.U.", x = "") + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("X1", "X2")),   
              map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]